# Text file being reset even when if condition not met. (C++)

Tags: c++

This code is supposed to reset the `High_Scores.txt` file if `y` is input by the user, but it's resetting it no matter what is input. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
// Reset 
// Include the libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

//Use the standard namespace
using namespace std;

// Declare global variables
char Ans;


void main()
{
    //Declare local variables
    int High_Score[5];
    string High_Score_Name[5];
    int Rank;

    // Initialize a high score at 0
    High_Score[4] = 0;

    // Input the high scores from a file
    ifstream Input_High_Scores;
    Input_High_Scores.open("High_Scores.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Input_High_Scores >> High_Score[i];
        Input_High_Scores >> High_Score_Name[i];
    }
    Input_High_Scores.close();

    if (High_Score[4] == 0)
    {

        //Initialize local variables
        High_Score[0] = 25000;
        High_Score[1] = 12000;
        High_Score[2] = 7500;
        High_Score[3] = 4000;
        High_Score[4] = 2000;
        High_Score_Name[0] = "Gwyneth";
        High_Score_Name[1] = "Adam";
        High_Score_Name[2] = "Nastasia";
        High_Score_Name[3] = "Nicolas";
        High_Score_Name[4] = "Dani";
    }




    // Print the high score list
    cout << "High Score List" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
    {
        cout << High_Score[i] << " " << High_Score_Name[i] << endl;
    }

    // Output the high scores to a file




    cout << "Would you like to reset the high scores list? (y or n)" << endl;
    cin >> Ans; 

    if (Ans = 'y')
    {

        //Initialize local variables
        High_Score[0] = 25000;
        High_Score[1] = 12000;
        High_Score[2] = 7500;
        High_Score[3] = 4000;
        High_Score[4] = 2000;
        High_Score_Name[0] = "Gwyneth";
        High_Score_Name[1] = "Adam";
        High_Score_Name[2] = "Nastasia";
        High_Score_Name[3] = "Nicolas";
        High_Score_Name[4] = "Dani";
        // Output the high scores to a file
        ofstream Output_High_Scores;
        Output_High_Scores.open("High_Scores.txt");
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=`: `Ans == 'y'`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I remember changing that to try to fix it, so there must have been some other errors also. It works great now, thanks again!

Comment: BTW, check the compiler warnings. It could be one if assignment is used within conditional operator.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with `if (Ans = 'y')`, use `if (Ans == 'y')`. Observe **==** in `if` condition. When you use `=`, the condition is true (in this scenario), no matter what is your input.

Comment: true in this case, but 'if (var = other_var)' has usages - e.g.: 'if (derived = dynamic_cast<Derived>(base))' is a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You're **assigning** a value to Ans in your if statement, not checking for *equal*: `if (Ans = 'y')` 
 as already pointed out in comment.

Answer (score 0):

small, but serious mistake you are doing hear.

```
if (Ans = 'y')
```

As you write the code, this suppose to be a condition. But you are not checking a condition hear. Insted you are assigning `'y'` values yo `Ans`.

Note that, `=` is use to assign and `==` is use to say equality.

So you should change your if statement condition to

```
if (Ans == 'y')
```